# SVG or Canvas! Which is better for charts?

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, charts

I am going to plot some heavy data centric charts on my website. I have a choice of SVG or Canvas. Which one will be a better choice? And any suggestions on what sort of frameworks I should evaluate and use?

Comment: If you're targeting desktop and have intense data visualization requirements use D3 (svg based).  For mobile, use a good canvas charting library. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The D3 library is currently the standard for data visualization. That being said, if you are using a framework perhaps look into a framework specific library?

For example, AngularJS has a corresponding NVD3 library which simplifies the setup process. If you are willing to learn D3, you will find that the flexibility offered should fit almost all applications!

http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/3HL4a/13/

Here is an example chart with some sorting functionality.

Note that with d3, it is very easy to manage your data:

```
var dataset = [ 
    { key: 0, value: 5 },
    { key: 1, value: 10 },
    { key: 2, value: 13 },
    { key: 3, value: 19 },
    { key: 4, value: 21 },
    { key: 5, value: 25 },
    { key: 6, value: 22 },
    { key: 7, value: 18 },
    { key: 8, value: 15 },
    { key: 9, value: 13 },
    { key: 10, value: 11 },
    { key: 11, value: 12 },
    { key: 12, value: 15 },
    { key: 13, value: 20 },
    { key: 14, value: 18 },
    { key: 15, value: 17 },
    { key: 16, value: 16 },
    { key: 17, value: 18 },
    { key: 18, value: 23 },
    { key: 19, value: 25 } ];
```

A simple set of string:value pairs as such could easily be generated from a script or DB.

Answer (score 0):

I have had fantastic luck with http://www.chartjs.org/ which uses Canvas

unless you need interactivity then use http://www.highcharts.com/